# Thread shows error

Tags: android, eclipse

Timer is a TextView and during run times throws error

**[threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4b5c648)]**

**[FATAL EXCEPTION: main]**

**[android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0]**

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.level_twolayout);
    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        try {
                            sleep(1000);
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
   error-------->   Timer.setText(i);
                    }
                }
            };t1.start();
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: A gentle advice and a precaution for all the future exception you might encounter ---->  handle any/just UI operations in ui thread like this `runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){ Timer.setText(i); } );`

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the text like this

`Timer.setText(i + "");`

This is because the `setText(int resId)` version will be invoked when you pass in an int value when you really wanted to invoke the `setText(String text)` version

The compiler/IDE does not give an error here. The int version looks for a corresponding String resource which doesn't exist and gives you the error.

Check this link for mode info [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).

Answer (score 1):

change

```
Timer.setText(i);
```

to

```
Timer.setText(String.valueOf(i));
```

Here `i` is an `Integer` value. You cann't assign `Integer` value as `TextView` text you have to convert it to `String` first.

Comment: If you explain why to the OP, your post will probably attract more votes.

Comment: If I change to Timer.setText(String.valueOf(i)); then also the same problem the program is not executing comes out.

Comment: At first first i converted to string and executed that also did not work.

Comment: If u run the above code in eclipse u will find the error.

Comment: Instead of Timer.setText(String.valueOf(i));I have changed with Toastmessage. Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  Still its throws the error msg.'